# iptables + ipset: принцип работы

Tags: iptables, ddos, linux

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вот решил попробовать защитить свой сервер. Наткнулся на `ipset`. Нашел пример:

```
ipset -N blacklist iphashiptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -m set --set blacklist src -j DROP
```

Он работает, но вот что он делает я не понимаю, банит `ip`? Если да, то можно ли посмотреть список. Ну или как можно реализовать что бы если `iptables` нашел бота, то банился его ip.

Comment: @avengerweb, если Вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создали хэш  blacklist, он пустой. Правилом iptables вы будите блокировать всех из хэша blacklist кто пойдет  к вам на хост на 80 порт. Если ip источника будет в хэше то будет DROP. Проверить кто в хэше

> ipset -L blacklist

Добавить в хэш

> ipset -A blacklist 1.1.1.1

Это все конечно хорошо и удобно но список ручками править придется. Каждый айпи заносить в хэш таблицу. Т.е это не автоматизированное средство.

Еще пример того как малой кровью можно организовать какую-никакую защиту.Воспользоватся модулем limit.

Создадим цепочку

> iptables -N dummy_bot

Пустим в нее тех кто идет на 80 порт

> iptables -A INPUT -p tcp  --dport 80 --syn -j dummy_bot

Предположим что бот будет делать больше 5 запросов за 10 секунд, тогда

> iptables -A dummy_bot -m limit --limit 5/10s --limit-burst 6 -j RETURN

Если не превышает, то действие RETURN.

А если превышает, то

> iptables -A dummy_bot -j DROP

Дропаем такого.

Comment: Не подскажите как можно автоматизировать сей процесс?

Comment: А вы сначала ТЗ поставьте а то не понятно что за боты, как отличить их от обычных юзеров, что будет являться критерием "ботничества" ?

Comment: Да просто, на кол-во соединений. Я пока не очень в этом разбираюсь, хотя бы подскажите как записывать в банлист можно

Comment: баню таким образом брутфорсеров на 22 порт... можно почитать про fail2ban, там описаны принципы работы, все автоматизировано.

Comment: Все же, как можно добавлять в ipset адреса, автоматом?

Comment: bash костылем, смотреть лог, искать тех кто долбиться, брать из лога айпи и заносить в айписет.

Comment: Чтоб банить автоматом, то надо писать скрипты, которые будут парсить лог файлы и смотреть, кого банить, а кого нет...